# how to make navigation down to google nexus menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a menu that look like google nexus 7 on the top of my page! i have another navigation menu in the middle of page. when i click on google menu it appear under the navigation menu. how can i show it upon of navigation menu?

here is my code:

```
<body>
<div id="page">
    <div id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <ul id="gn-menu" class="gn-menu-main">
            <li class="gn-trigger">
                <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-menu"><span>Menu</span></a>
                <nav class="gn-menu-wrapper">
                    <div class="gn-scroller">
                        <ul class="gn-menu">
                            <li class="gn-search-item">
                                <input placeholder="جستجو" type="search" class="gn-search">
                                <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-search"><span>Search</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-download">دانلود</a>
                                </li>
                                    <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-article">اخبار</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-pictures">عکس ها</a></li>


                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-cog">مدیریت</a></li>
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-help">راهنمای سایت</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /gn-scroller -->
                </nav>
            </li>

            <li><a class="login-page" href="http://tympanus.net/codrops">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>حساب کاربری</a></li>
            <li><a class="login-page" href="http://tympanus.net/Development/HeaderEffects/">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span><span>تماس با ما</span></a></li>


        </ul>

    </div><!-- /container -->


    </div> <!-- /header -->

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="container" id="main-container">


             <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

                  </ul>


                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
              </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>



        </div> <!-- /container -->

    </div> <!-- /wrapper -->


</div> <!-- /page -->
```

[here is first picture of my problem](http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00498/zr12hxe55n14.png)

[and here is the second](http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00498/kufsgrduqmd7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's hard to tell 100% without your CSS but it appears to be a `z-index` issue. Try bumping up your `z-index` to a high number:

```
z-index: 1000000; //some high number
```